# Django: set default value for new model field which has unique=True

Tags: python, django, django-models

There is a custom user model which inherits `AbstractUser` in Django.

The model has `username = None`, below is the model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email address"), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
```

I want to remove `username = None` so that we can save usernames as well.

But the issues is we have various users in the database.

and when I remove the `username = None` and try to migrate, I get the prompt:

**It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'username' to user without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:**

1. **Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)**
2. **Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.**

I don't want to override the `username` field of `AbstractUser` class.

`AbstractUser > username`:

```
username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        _("username"),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_(
            "Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only."
        ),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            "unique": _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
```

I want `username` to take value of `email` if a different value is not provided.

How can I provide the default value?

Comment: Do you need default value to be depending upon email or you want any default value ? As a unqiue default value `default=uuid.uuid4` this will work

Comment: @DeepakTripathi I want the previously present entries to have value of email.

Comment: means emails as a username in older entries?

Comment: For older values you can do `User.object.all().update(username=F("email"))`. This way all usernames will be filled with email

Comment: Why don't you want to override the `username` field? Seems to me like the most obvious way to deal with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom migration. When creating your migration, provide a default value, then edit the generated migration with something like this:

```
import django.contrib.auth.models
from django.db import migrations, models
import users.models


def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model("users", "User")
    User.objects.update(username=models.F("email"))


def reverse_func(apps, schema_editor):
    pass


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('users', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelManagers(
            name='user',
            managers=[
                ('manager', users.models.UserManager()),
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='username',
            field=models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, null=True),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, reverse_func),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='username',
            field=models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Here's the explanation of the changes:

- First, make the column nullable by adding `null=True` to the new `username` field.
- Update the username column of existing users via `RunPython` action. In the `forward_func`, we use the value of `email` column for `username`. Reverse function can be empty because the column will be removed.
- Now you can make the field required by setting `null` to its default value, `False`, via `AlterField`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I solved the problem using the same approach. But instead of creating 1 migration I created 2. I'll optimise it and create only 1 migration.

Comment: @CoolBreeze cool! So if the solution worked, can you please mark it as accepted? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pre_save` singal like that:

```
# signals.py

from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def fill_username(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.username:
        instance.username = instance.email

# apps.py

class UserConfig(AppConfig):
    ...

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

In this way it will always check if username is entered. In case it's empty it will copy value from email.

For existing Users you might need to call save() manually or with for loop in shell:

```
$ python manage.py shell

>> from users.models import User
>> for user in User.objects.all():
...    user.username = user.email
...    user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use migration for older values and write the setter for username in your Serializer for the new entries